# 404 error when doing restore content database

Tags: backup, restore, content-database

Im trying to copy content database(one web application, exacly what I want) from our production- to our test-Environment.

Im using [this guidefor backing up](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748650.aspx) (the CA-alternative). When I use the [corresponding guide to restore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748647.aspx)  my web application on test.

I get no errors during restore, but when I go to the startpage I get *"404 - page not found"* (plain text message). I can go to *some* of SPs application pages, and by going to /_layouts/sitemanager.aspx I can see that all content, including the pages are there. But I when I go to /_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx for example I get either  *"404 - page not found"* (plain text message) or, for some pages, a SharePoint standard error *the page could not be found.*

During restore I get to choose in a tree view (Farm is top node) what Items to backup. Here I select my web application further down the tree. Is this correct. I notice a note in the backup-guide that says

> The web application might consist of several components. You must
>   select the top-level component.

But top level of what? must I include som settings to do a correct Restore? Is it an AAM-error? (if so, what AAM-settings should I have)

**UPDATE:**

**It seems to be that the master page cannot be found** (even though its there), **I changed master page and all of the application pages worked.

(I tried to modify this question to solve the new problems , but it got to messy, I will post a new one instead...)

Comment: Can you try going to `_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx` The 15 is required if you are on SP 2013 or 14 if you are on 2010

Comment: Hi, Ive got same result. (Im actually att settings.aspx and clicking around)

Comment: Check the log files for more details of error.

Comment: Hi Amal. Good Idea, just did. (see modified question). Im past the 404-errors but I still have problems finding masterpage and all our features... will post a new question about that after som investigation

Comment: I suppose you are accepting @AmalHashim's suggestion as an answer to this question then? :-)